# MySQL - java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet is from UPDATE. No Data

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
public static void main(String args[])
    {

            SQLConnector sqlConnect = new SQLConnector();
            Connection conn = null;
            try
            {
            conn= sqlConnect.getConnection();
            CallableStatement cStmt = conn.prepareCall("{ call test(?,?,?)}");
            cStmt.setDouble(1, 100.0);
            cStmt.setInt(2, 1);
            cStmt.registerOutParameter(3, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
            ResultSet rs = cStmt.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString(3);
                }
            cStmt.execute();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally
            {
                sqlConnect.closeConnection(conn);
            }
        }
```

This snippet throws the error

```
java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet is from UPDATE. No Data.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
```

But if I pass the same parameters from MySQL Workbench it gives proper output.

I am using MySQLServer 5.6.25 and MySQLConnector 5.1.6.

Please help me solve this problem. This looks like a bug in the way I call MySQL from Java

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See section 4 of this MySQL documentation page: [Using JDBC CallableStatements to Execute Stored Procedures](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-statements-callable.html).

You don't use `executeQuery()`. You have to use `execute()` and `getResultSet()`.

Since you *know* the statement will return exactly one `ResultSet`, your code becomes:

```
cStmt.execute();
try (ResultSet rs = cStmt.getResultSet()) {
    if (rs.next())
        System.out.println(rs.getString(3));
}
```

Except of course you might be wrong, because the call doesn't return a result set, but instead returns a string in an output parameter, and that totally changes the code:

```
cStmt.execute();
System.out.println(cStmt.getString(3));
```

Answer (score 1):

**Remove the below line in your code to resolve the issue:**

cStmt.execute();

Answer (score 0):

it's all about changes in your procedure

remove **into declared_veritable**   from procedure

because at the end you will get all data from result-set only so no need to provide into clause in your select query of procedure.